# windows phone use GestureService dynamic throw nullreferenceexcpetion

Tags: windows-phone-8, nullreferenceexception, toolkit

I use the toolkit GestureService dynamic, the code below put in Page construction is ok, but in the tap of control such as Grid,StackPanel will throw the nullreferenceexcpetion.

```
private void TitlePanel_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) {
    Image img = new Image();
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("/Assets/background.png", UriKind.Relative);
    img.Source = bitmapImage;
    var gesture = GestureService.GetGestureListener(img);
}
```

The exception stacktrace is:

```
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.RaiseGestureEvent[T](Func`2 eventGetter, Func`1 argsGetter, Boolean releaseMouseCapture)
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.OnTap(Object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as :

```
private void TitlePanel_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) {
    Image img = new Image();        
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/background.png", UriKind.Relative));;
    if(null != img)
    {
          var gesture = GestureService.GetGestureListener(img);
          //Apply your tap events for gesture if you need here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry sir, the class BitmapImage doesn't contain the method BeginInit or EndInit in windows phone 8 platform.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the real difference between our code? My code can put in the Page Construction, is ok.

Comment: what you are trying to say? Not getting what you said

Answer (score 0):

You Should try [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/08/31/xna-from-silverlight-on-windows-phone-7-gestures.aspx) code. It Should work with Grid.

Comment: Thank you! That code is ok, maybe I use GestureService dynamic. :(